# Simple Django Aggregation - Optimization

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I'm reading the beginnings of [annotating and aggregating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) and I'm wondering which way is best to complete the following situation:

You want to count the number of authors for each book in a queryset. The tutorial suggests the following with `annotate`:

```
Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors'))
```

My question is, why do it this way when you can accomplish this with model instance methods:

```
#models.py
class Book(models.Model):
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

  def author_count(self):
    return self.authors.count()

#views.py
books = Book.objects.all()

#template.html
{% for book in books %}
  {{ book.author_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is one situation better than the other? Are there optimization benefits I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Because then you will have to query the model:

```
Books.objects.all()  # Or any other filter
```

and then you call `count()` - Once you do it for multiple objects(books) you will hit the DB for each book you call `count()` on!

When using `annotate` you will hit the DB only once, and get the result as a dict/list for **all** the books in the query.